# UbuntuDDE Remix 20.04 installation manual partitioning stuck

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, desktop-environments, 20.04

I've been using win10 dual booted with Ubuntu18.04, and I want to upgrade from 18.04 to UbuntuDDE Remix 20.04.
I want the system to boot quickly, so I allocated 40GB SSD to root and 100GB HDD to /home. However, it gave me a warning which said:

> An EFI system partition is necessary to start UbuntuDDE.
>   To configure an EFI system partition, go back and select or create a FAT32 filesystem with the esp flag enabled and mount point /boot/efi.
>   You can continue without setting up an EFI system partition but your system may fail to start.

I don't know much about this, but I think that I'll have to make another partition for the EFI, but I'm not sure whether to make it in SSD or HDD and what size it should be. What should I do?
Also, do I need to make any partitions other than the ones stated above? I've come across tutorials where they create a swap partition, but I left it because I wasn't sure how much memory to allocate to it, and it can be done after the installation as well.

Comment: I don't know what "UbuntuDDE Remix" is. It is likely off topic here. Anyway, there is probably no UEFI mode available, so you can't install it.

Comment: It's Ubuntu with the deepin desktop environment(DDE).

Comment: It is an odd choice not to provide legacy mode. Here is their support page: https://ubuntudde.com/support/.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   UbuntuDDE is a *respin* and not a *flavor*, it may become an official flavor, which was blogged about, but that won't happen this year.

Answer (score 0):

UEFI requires the efi partition (FAT32 and flagged "boot" or "esp"). Any size over 200MB works, but I've seen 512MB most commonly, since this is still a tiny fraction of SSDs these days. This is where the EFI boot info is stored for all the OS's installed on your computer. Google EFI partition and there are a lot of articles describing how to manually create. Of course the partition is created automatically by the OS installers if your computer BIOS is set for UEFI MODE -- but NOT if your BIOS is set for Legacy Mode.

If you have 8GB or more of RAM I wouldn't bother with a swap partition if you have an SSD system drive. It's not required, doesn't speed things up noticeably with SSDs I've heard, and puts unnecessary wear on the life of the SSD, although that's less of a problem in the past few years with greatly increased SDD endurance.